# Using jQuery to hide div scrollbar, but retain scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar

I am trying to be able to scroll inside one div but without showing the actual scrollbar.

I need the user to be able to scroll using the scrollwheel

Does anyone have ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to be able to scroll it if scrollbar is missing? middle mouse? click dragging? hovering over top or bottom?

Comment: Drat! Sorry! You're right! :) Scrollwheel / Middle mouse. (Updating question)

Comment: You could do something like this with css, hmm.... http://jsfiddle.net/c7tR8/ the only problem is it isn't very obvious that there is more content in the div when you can't see a scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to implement this and see if it works :) 

I agree that it's a problem if it isn't obvious, but I will try to reflect that in my design!

Comment: Something about doing it that way just feels dirty... like I'm missing something important that's wrong with it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either :/ I think it's because I don't have a set height

Comment: Yes, you definitely need a set height for this to work.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to do without?

Comment: The inner div needs to be the same height as the outer div, otherwise it won't scroll properly. You could set that height with javascript at run-time if needed.

Comment: Kevin, you were absolutely right. Setting the inner div to 100% works perfectly. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, the real reason would be why you would want that, but since you asked I will try and solve your issue.

You will need two divs. One nested inside the other.

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">
        Scrolling Content Goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```

You will then need some CSS to help this situation out. The overflow:auto will give you the scrolling once it goes past the height limitations. I put on an random width for sake of the example. Putt a padding on the right hand side to push the scroll bar out of the .outer div class. This way you won't have to worry about the content going under the .outer div.

```
.inside { width: 500px; overflow: auto; height: 300px; padding-right: 20px; }
```

for the outer class you will need to specify the same height, same width, but overflow:hidden.

```
.outside { width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
```

EXAMPLE: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBdMf/1/)

Comment: This is not consistent in different zoom levels - the width of the scollbar usually change with the zoom level thus making the scollbar visible for (a really strange) browser setup. Also, maybe more realistic than overly awkward zooms, different browsers will have different wide scrollbars not making it as universal as it could be. 
This is indeed so obscure that no one should (usually have to) worry about it, but I just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use css and hide or do some styling with it so it looks hidden. Here's one some links I found.

http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/scrollbars.html

Answer (score 0):

This was tested in IE and Firefox - both handle padding a little differently, so I am using height and width to account for content visibility.

It makes sense to have 2 containers - one for the container and one for the content, however since browsers handle padding differently, it's a lot harder than you think to push the scrollbar into the hidden area.  This is where the third container comes in:

- One container for the parent dimensions without scrollbars
- One container that contains the scrollbar which is pushed into the hidden area
- One container that houses the content with the correct width set

This is accomplished through stylesheet tricks - the stylesheet has been commented so you can follow the instructions / comments in there.

Hope this helps! :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* Propetary paragraph style */
    p {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px 7px 0px;
    }
    /* Global notes:
       - Since the 
    /* This is the outer container - set desired height and width here */
    .scrollabelDivContainer {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 2px dashed #ddd;
    }
    /* This is the div inside the container - the height should 
       match the container and width be more (to push the 
       scrollbar into the hidden content area) */
    .scrollableDiv {
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    /* This houses the content.  Set the widget 10px less than the 
       container width to ensure the content is visible in all browsers */
    .scrollableDivContent {
        width: 290px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="scrollabelDivContainer">
        <div class="scrollableDiv">
            <div class="scrollableDivContent">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tincidunt consequat urna ut tincidunt. Vestibulum molestie leo quis dui malesuada vulputate eget tempor purus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras nec orci enim, vel tristique lectus. Sed lobortis ultrices enim eu consequat.</p>
                <p>Integer magna lectus, iaculis sit amet interdum nec, ullamcorper ut purus. Sed aliquam sollicitudin lacinia. Proin porttitor aliquet lorem, eu dictum lorem suscipit et. Ut vestibulum eros quis turpis auctor id sollicitudin risus faucibus. Quisque volutpat nibh ut sem euismod rutrum. Ut eget orci non quam scelerisque laoreet sit amet a metus. Mauris aliquam facilisis lacinia.<p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```