# can't hide scrollbar when using overflow: auto

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS:

```
.div {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    height: 414px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 902px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

I tried with `overflow-y: hidden;`, scrollbar disappear but scroll isn't working. Hope you understand what I want...
Also, should I use auto or scroll? With auto I see horizontal bar too.

Here is JSFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/sp95S/**
Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to happen? This is the correct behaviour.

Comment: I want to hide scrollbar without affecting scrolling.

Comment: How would you scroll the content then?!

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page (check out the second answer)

Comment: @DannyBeckett keyboard arrows or mouse wheel?

Comment: You need to use JavaScript in that case. CSS alone cannot do what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to hide div scrollbar, but retain scrolling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186100/using-jquery-to-hide-div-scrollbar-but-retain-scrolling)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create an inner div: http://jsfiddle.net/sp95S/1/

```
.div {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    height: 214px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 452px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#inner{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Very smart answer !

Answer (score 14):

If you want to hide the scrollbar, but keep the functionality, you can use:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems like you want to have the page still scroll without the scrollbar showing.

This has been answered here a couple of times already:

- [hide scrollbar while still able to scroll with mouse/keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293650/hide-scrollbar-while-still-able-to-scroll-with-mouse-keyboard/)
- [Hiding the scrollbar on an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)

Basically you can use javascript (or jquery, though you don't necessarily need it). On webkit browsers, there is a function to hide the scrollbars:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
display: none; 
}
```

but it won't work for firefox or internet explorer or opera.

Comment: This *might* work on Opera, since it now runs Webkit, but I still wouldn't use it, since it won't work on anything other than Webkit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the scroll bar, but maintain scroll you can look into a plugin called [slimscroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll). The scroll bar is there but it can be configure to be rather un-noticable.

http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll