# how to hide scrollbar in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide scrollbar, but at the same, i also want to have scrolling action i.e
I want to hide scrollbar but still, want to scroll to see rest of content without actually seeing the scrollbar.

`overflow: hidden` won't work because after using that I cannot scroll to see the content.

how to do that using HTML/CSS/javascript?

I am working on styling scrollbar but I noticed there is no well-defined way to style scroll bar so I made custom scrollbar using divs with jQuery, but at the end, I have two scroll bar one which I made and other default scrollbar and now I want to hide default scroll bar.

I don't want to use -webkit- because it is not accepted in all browser.

I want to hide scroll bar in the following code.

```css
  .container{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.sidebarcontainer{
  width: 300PX;
  height: 6000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.innersidebarcontainer{
  position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar{
  width: 300px;
  background-color: teal;
  height: 2000px;
  top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}
.mainpage{
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  height: 6000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.footer{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer">
      <div class="innersidebarcontainer">
        <div class="sidebar">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainpage">
      <div class="page"></div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

please anybody answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: Or is this what you want?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447384/cant-hide-scrollbar-when-using-overflow-auto

Answer (score 2):

And     overflow:auto; is out of the question?

It won't show if you don't need but does show when you do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following styles:

```
#parent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-right: 17px;
}
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/954/

Comment: could you provide the solution with respect to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourDiv::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Works only for webkit based browsers

Answer (score 0):

Make your scroll bar transparent. You can do this by the following code.

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar
    {
        width:0px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
    {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
```

Hope this will help you!